# Implementation of Thread Constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Thread a = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override         
    Public void run(){

    }
});
```

When `start()` is invoked on a run method on the anonymous runnable object will be invoked. What might be the implementation in the Thread constructor to make it happen?

Will it cast the anonymous runnable object to a Thread object in some way and point it to a?

Comment: Did you try checking [the source](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Thread-source.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Thread` constructor uses the given `Runnable` object as the thread's *delegate*.

All of the magic happens in the `start()` method.  That's the method that creates a new operating system thread, and arranges for `this.run()` to be called within it.

If `this` is a subclass of `Thread`, then `this.run()` calls the subclass's `run()` method.

If `this` is a `Thread` instance with a delegate, then `this.run()` calls the delegate's `run()` method.

If `this` is a `Thread` instance with no delegate, then `this.run()` returns without doing anything, and the new thread immediately terminates.